# Sql command for inserting value that will be bigger in 1 then the maximal value

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql

I need that the minimal id will be 0(zero).

I tried something like this:

```
INSERT INTO users(id, name) 
VALUES ( (SELECT MAX(id) FROM users) + 1 , 'andrey6' )
```

But I have a problem when the "users" table is empty, I just cant figure out how to keep the minimal value to be 0.

Comment: Which database, MySQL or PostgreSQL? Why aren't you using autoincrement/serial for this sort of thing? Correctly managing this yourself is trickier than you might think.

Comment: @muistooshort I smell the XY problem here. OP—although the code below looks like it does what you want, **it isn't concurrent-safe!** Use `SERIAL` or the equivalent auto-increment function of your database.

Answer (score 1):

Does this do what you want:

```
INSERT INTO users(id, name) 
VALUES ( (SELECT IFNULL(MAX(id) + 1,0) FROM users) , 'andrey6' )
```

?

Comment: I get:
  function if(integer, integer, integer) does not exist

Answer (score 1):

You could just use [`COALESCE`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-conditional.html#FUNCTIONS-COALESCE-NVL-IFNULL) like so:

```
INSERT INTO users(id, name) 
VALUES ( (SELECT COALESCE(MAX(id), 0) FROM users) + 1 , 'andrey6' )
```